# Display object propery in ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a custom object which holds details about a project resource.
Properties are PersonName, Position and Id
If the resource isn't filled, PersonName is set to 'Unassgined'.

To add an object to a Combobox, I do:

```
    var avail = s.GetUnassignedPrintRoles(SprintId);
    foreach (var o in avail)
    {
        cmbRoles.Items.Add(o);
    }
```

This is fine when displaying a list of resources. My object has an overridden ToString() method:

```
public override string ToString()
        {
            if(AssignedPerson != null)
                return ResourceType + " - " + AssignedPerson.Firstname + " " + AssignedPerson.Surname;
            return "Unassigned";
        }
```

But, I have a screen that shows a list of roles that are not assigned. So, I get a list, where the Person is NULL.

But, I want to display the 'Role' in the ComboxBox.

But, my object's ToString shows 'Unassigned'. How can I make it display the Role property? Is there a way to save the object in the Comboxbox item, but display a different propery in the display, other than what I have set in the ToString override?

Comment: Might be a silly thing to ask, but have you tried setting the DisplayMember and ValueMember properties of the combobox respectively?

Comment: Nope... never knew about this. Will need to look it up. Not sure how I'd assign it. Edit: Fixed! Thanks!

Comment: What about using a [bindingsource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.aspx) and setting [displayMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember.aspx) of the comboBox?

Comment: I might be cheeky and add mine as an answer even though others have already said.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With regards to my comment, it might be needed to set the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` properties of the ComboBox, like so;

```
cmbRoles.DisplayMember = "Role";
cmbRoles.ValueMember = "Id";
cmbRoles.DataSource = avail;
```

This way your ComboBox will Display the role, but the underlying data will be the ID, So when you select via the `SelectedValue` property, you'll get the ID.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the DisplayMember property to distinguish the displayed value and the actual value? If you do that, you should be able to set the Role as the displayed entry on the combobox.

```
cmbRoles.DisplayMember = "" + Role;
cmbRoles.ValueMember = "Id";
cmbRoles.DataSource = avail;
```

I'm not sure what Role is in your code but you should be able to get the gist from that.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove ToString() altogether by using read-only property:

```
public string FullInfo
{
    get
    {
       return ResourceType + " - " + AssignedPerson.Firstname + " " + AssignedPerson.Surname;
    }
}
```

then

```
 comboBox.DisplayMember = "FullInfo";
 comboBox.ValueMember = "Id";
 comboBox.DataSource = avail;
```

and you can do any kind of properties like this.

Answer (score 1):

Add this ,

```
private void InitializeComponent()
    {
      cmbRoles.ValueMember = "id"; 
      cmbRoles.DisplayMember = "discription";
    }
```